# Blank screen after login after using Testdisk

Tags: boot, hard-drive, login, testdisk

I was trying to recover a corrupted EXTERNAL hard drive using TestDisk.

After reboot, the  external hard drive seemed to be detected but I cannot login to my Ubuntu account. When I login, the GUI doesn't load. Just the purple wallpaper.

I can only either login as a Guest (and not access my files) or login via Ctrl+Alt+F1. Because I can login via the terminal, I see my files are still intact.

My question is how do I be able to use my account normally (with the GUI)? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. It was because my hard drive was full. I uninstalled something and it's fine now.